# Excel Solver Linear Optimization : Formula Debugging

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to get a optimization model to work correctly. The background is to use the solver to find a circuit (AC or DC) that would minimize cost. I am trying to use binary variables so the circuits (decision variables) can only use one decision variables (either AC or DC)

The issue seems to be that I am multiplying the decision variables by the binary variables. Which makes it non-linear and IT HAS TO BE linear. However it does not work correctly when using the non-linear method as well

Any help is greatly appreciated Attached is my hand written formulation

Looking to know if this is a math error on my part or an error with the excel solver [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXwc0.png)

Answer (score 2):

Your big-M constraints $(2)$ already enforce $Y_i = 0 \implies D_i = 0$, so you can replace $D_i Y_i$ with just $D_i$ in $(1)$.  Similar story for $A_i$ and $v_i$, but you should have written $A_i \le M v_i$ in $(2)$.